# OpenDroneMap: How to produce correct georeference ortophoto from UAV?

Tags: georeferencing, orthophoto, photogrammetry, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, opendronemap

I am trying to produce proper georeferenced ortophotomap from UAV mission using OpenDroneMap (ODM), like I have done the same thing using APS Suite from Menci

In both cases I have the same images with EXIF coordinates.
The ortophotomap from APS Suite looks good, there is 1-2m georeference error.
Using the ODP, I lanuched the processing with the default parameters:

python run.py --project-path path/to/project

and it produced ortophotomap with 400m georeference error. The output image is also reversed.
[image]

How can I produce ortophoto using ODM to get more similar results like the one from APS Suite?

Comment: Have you tried posting this to the issues page at github? https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap/issues

Comment: What software are you using since you did not mention in your tags ?

Comment: @Robert, left the comment: Have you tried posting this to the issues page at github? 
https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap/issues

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you have to convert first your coordinate reference (GCP)'s frame to overlaid map. If you used different coordinate systems (Datum) or zones it can be shifted.

Comment: Just check some road corners from overlaid map and your mosaics, so use new coordinates as GCP in your project.